# Does software update decrease device performance?

Tags: battery-life, android-10, performance, samsung-galaxy-tab, android-11

I’ve been using an Android tablet for a month, and I’ve just got a notification on an update for my tab for Android 11 or One UI 3 (not sure if they mean the same thing). I’m on Android 10.

Based on my experience in using iOS devices, every major update decreases my older device’s performance and battery life for some reason. I’m used to seeing updates as something to avoid.

Do software updates have any bad effects on an Android device’s performance/battery life?

Comment: Apps tend to grow because of new features, new bug fixes for certain devices or Android versions. Larger apps have more code to execute, and require more RAM.